# Spring/JPA - Best way to query

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, jackson

I'm pretty new using Spring. I use it to make Restful services.
I was asking myself how to make a simple query with relationships without getting all the information from the related item.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;
    String bar1, bar2, bar3...barN;

    //My approach to avoid get unused data in the json serialization
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"bar1", "bar2"..., "name", "fooMother", foo"Father"})
    Foo fooFather;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"bar1", "bar2"..., "name", "fooMother", foo"Father"})
    Foo fooMother;

//Constructors, getters, setters
}

//Here is where I want to get the data of a Foo instance (just FK in the relationships)
@GetContoller
public Foo getFoo(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id) {
    return fooRespository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException());
}
```

As far as I have read:

- I should use lazy fetch to avoid automatic relationship searching in DB but when my controller returns Foo jackson will see the relationship getters and even if it's a lazy fetch it will map them.
- My approach it's horrible, actually I have a class with 10 attributes and manage that thing it's awful.
- Other option I have seen it's to create a DAO or DTO to map the query result from JPA but it seems I already have a "FooDTO" as a request content and it seems that if my application will evolve with that approach I will end with FooQuery1Dto, FooQuery2Dto, etc..
- I had the idea to create custom queries but it seems unforgiven having Spring to make custom queries for everything and even so as far as I experimented it will do the same Jackson makes his magic.
- Custom Deserialization, the same problem, a lot of customs.
- Maybe a dynamic way to query and map (without creating classes and classes)?

So, I'm not sure how to act. Maybe I should choose one of them, or there are other ways I didn't find, so the question is (and I'm pretty sure there will be no absolute answer and Spring will not solve all my problems but I need opinions) what should I do if I want scalability and performance?

I will be so grateful if somebody recommend me a good source to this kind of good practices in Spring because searching I found a lot of material with diverse practices and opinions.

EDIT: Well, it seems that as I hope there is no "perfect" answer, but I've discovered JsonView that helps to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to **not mix the Json configuration with the Entity configuration**: split the responsabilities between the Json and JPA Entity.

Use your entity only to retrieve the database information. Create another class, like a `FooJson` (or `FooResponse`, `FooDto`, etc) and fill the information that you want on the `FooJson` from the `Foo` entity, and return this `FooJson` on the controller. You can use some lib, like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org), to help you on this.

To retrieve the information from database, you can always use the `Foo` entity and map their informations for different Foo Json classes, like: `FooCreateJon`, `FooUpdateJson`, `FooFindByIdJson`, etc. You can use this strategy to return always a `Foo` entity if is not affecting the performance of your application.

About the code, you will have something like this:

```
@GetContoller
public FooJson getFoo(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id) {
    return fooService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new DataNotFoundException());
}
```

The `FooService`:

```
class FooService {

    FooJson findById(String id) {
        Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id);
        return new ModelMapper().map(FooJson.class, foo);
    }
}
```